# How do I convert an Ant Path into a FileSet?

Tags: ant, jakarta-ee

I'm writing an Ant script to package a project into a WAR file. The software consists of several projects with their own source directories, libraries, etc.

The WAR task has a nested element `lib` which I'm currently working on. I currently have a reference of the required libs as a `Path` (containing several `FileSets`, which I use in a classpath reference. The `lib`, however, wants the input to be a `FileSet`, and it refuses a `Path`.

I tried converting my `Path` into a `FileSet`, but then I didn't get it to work as a classpath elsewhere.

Is there a way to convert a `Path` into a `FileSet`? I would hate to copy-paste the directories.

```
<path id="compile.libs">
    <fileset dir="${common.path}/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
    <fileset dir="${data.path}/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
    <fileset dir="${gui.path}/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
    <fileset dir="${gui.path}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
</path>
```

...when used with `<war ..><../> <lib refid="compile.libs"/> </war>` leads to:

```
BUILD FAILED
build.xml:173: compile.libs doesn't denote a zipfileset or a fileset
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may have several choices.

1. You may provide more than one
   `<lib>` nested element to `<war>`
   task.  Maybe this would be enough.
2. You may preassemble all of your
   `lib` files in one temporary
   directory and then just reference that
   directory as a fileset.
3. There is an ant-contrib
   [PathToFileSet](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/pathtofileset.html) task, but it
   requires a central root directory,
   and this may not be a case with your
   `compile.libs` layout.
4. Since Ant 1.8.0 you can use a [mappedresources](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#mappedresources). Source: [Ant script: Prevent duplication of JAR in javac-classpath war-lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039505/ant-script-prevent-duplication-of-jar-in-javac-classpath-war-lib)

I think I would try option 1.

Answer (score 16):

Assuming the paths are absolute, you can first convert the `Path` to a comma-delimited list using `<pathconvert>`, and then convert the list back into a `Fileset`:

```
<!-- create path -->
<path id="foo.path">
    <pathelement location="/foo/bar/baz.txt"/>
    <pathelement location="/qux/quux/quuux.txt"/>
</path>

<!-- convert foo.path to foo.list -->
<pathconvert 
    refid="foo.path" 
    property="foo.list"
    pathsep=","
    dirsep="/"
>
    <!-- 
        <fileset> will want relative paths, so we need to strip 
        the leading /. result: "foo/bar/baz.txt,qux/quux/quuux.txt"
    -->
    <map from="/" to=""/> 
</pathconvert>

<!-- convert foo.list to fileset -->
<fileset id="foo.fileset" dir="/" includes="${foo.list}"/>
```

(Note the above assumes Unix; you may need to fiddle a bit with separators and whatnot if you're on Windows or you want to make it platform-independent.)

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by staging the libs like this :

```
<copy todir="stage/libs" flatten="true">
<path refid="classpath" />
</copy>
```

and then using a  in the WAR task.simple.

Answer (score -1):

The jars in the classpath used to compile are not the same that needs to be packaged inside the war. For example: I'm sure you need **servlet-api.jar** to compile your project but you don't need it inside the war because the container provides it. And some jars aren't needed at compile time but at runtime.
**I know I'm not answering your question, just want you to think what you are doing.**

Comment: While I'm aware of that problem, I appreciate the words of caution (for posterity). It would be great to be able to add exclusions to path refs. I would be ready to have fragments of paths, and then combining them into a larger one, if needed.