# Ant script: Prevent duplication of JAR in javac-classpath war-lib

Tags: ant, war

I have a ANT script and I have a lot of duplicated path to same set JAR files.
But there is so many double wording in the classpath and also in the war element.

```
<path id="my.classpath">
  <pathelement location="folderA/subFolderA/1.0/A.jar"/>
  <pathelement location="folderC/subFolderB/1.0/B.jar"/>
  <pathelement location="folderF/subFolderZ/2.0/Z.jar"/>
  <pathelement location="compile/subFolderX/1.0/onlyForJavac.jar"/>
</path>
....
<javac ...>
 <classpath refid="my.classpath" />
</javac>
....
<war ...>
 <lib file="folderA/subFolderA/1.0/A.jar"/>
 <lib file="folderC/subFolderB/1.0/B.jar"/>
 <lib file="folderF/subFolderZ/2.0/Z.jar"/>
 <lib file="moreFolderF/subFolderZ/2.0/additionFile.jar"/>
 <lib file="moreFolderF/subFolderZ/2.0/additionRuntimeFile.jar"/>
</war>
```

I want to summary them into ONE list which is easier to keep update.

But I am blocked as I have no idea how to share a path-like-structure with a fileset-like-structure.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since Ant 1.8.0 there is a new resource collection - [`mappedresources`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#mappedresources) that
can be used in place of the `war` task `lib` element.

So, the task might look like this (pretty much straight from the docs):

```
<war ... >
    <mappedresources>
        <restrict>
           <path refid="my.classpath"/>
           <type type="file"/>
        </restrict>
        <chainedmapper>
          <flattenmapper/>
          <globmapper from="*" to="WEB-INF/lib/*"/>
        </chainedmapper>
    </mappedresources>
</war>
```

This feature was added to resolve a [long-standing feature request](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=31947) to make
the task flatten jars when deploying to `WEB-INF/lib`.

*previous answer:*

Although you can't easily convert a path to a fileset with vanilla Ant, you can go the other way.
So one option would be to define your jars in a fileset, and derive the path from it.
Something like this perhaps:

```
<fileset id="my.fileset" dir="${basedir}">
    <include name="folderA/subFolderA/1.0/A.jar"/>
    <include name="folderC/subFolderB/1.0/B.jar"/>
    <include name="folderF/subFolderZ/2.0/Z.jar"/>
    <include name="moreFolderF/subFolderZ/2.0/additionFile.jar"/>
    <include name="moreFolderF/subFolderZ/2.0/additionRuntimeFile.jar"/>
</fileset>

<path id="my.classpath">
    <fileset refid="my.fileset" />
</path>

<!-- javac stays the same -->

<war ...>
    <lib refid="my.fileset" />
</war>
```

Another possibility is to use the [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) [`pathtofileset` task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/pathtofileset.html).

Comment: There is a problem, <war ...>
    <lib refid="my.fileset" />
</war>
it do create subfolders under WAR/WEB-INF/lib/

Comment: @Dennis - I updated the answer.  I wasn't aware of the issue with WEB-INF/lib 'non-flattening' before.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, possibly 'not the best' will be to place required jar file in WEB-INF/lib, and then set the classpath from there.

```
<path id="compile.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
</path>
```

When its time to build the war, you need not worry about the `<lib>` at all, as jars are already placed in WEB-INF/lib folder.

```
<war destfile="${dist.dir}/${project.name}.war" webxml="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <fileset dir="${web.dir}"/>
        <classes dir="${build.dir}/classes"/>
    </war>
```