# How can I pass a union to the war lib element?

Tags: ant, war

I am trying to refactor an ant `build.xml` file to reduce duplication.  Previously the file had a bunch of targets something like this:

```
<war ...>
    <lib dir=${lib}">
        <include name="foo.jar"/>
        <include name="bar.jar"/>
        <include name="qux.jar"/>
    </lib>
    ...
</war>

<jar ...>
    ...
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Class-Path" value="foo.jar bar.jar baz.jar"/>
    </manifest>
</jar>
```

Despite the ant documentation, I got it to the point where it looks more like this:

```
<fileset id="commonLibs1" dir="${lib}">
    <include name="foo.jar"/>
    <include name="bar.jar"/>
</fileset>

<union id="clientLibs">
    <fileset refid="commonLibs1"/>
    <fileset dir="${lib}">
        <include name="baz.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</union>

<war ...>
    <lib dir=${lib}">
        <include name="foo.jar"/>
        <include name="bar.jar"/>
        <include name="qux.jar"/>
    </lib>
    ...
</war>

<manifestclasspath property="tmpClassPath" jarfile="./placeholdername.jar">
    <classpath>
        <resources refid="clientLibs"/>
    </classpath>
</classpath>

<jar ...>
    ...
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${tmpClasspath}"/>
    </manifest>
</jar>
```

Which is swell.  Now I've almost reached my goal of not having all these jar names copied all over the place:

```
    <fileset id="commonLibs1" dir="${lib}">
    <include name="foo.jar"/>
    <include name="bar.jar"/>
</fileset>

<union id="clientLibs">
    <fileset refid="commonLibs1"/>
    <fileset dir="${lib}">
        <include name="baz.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</union>

<union id="serverLibs">
    <fileset refid="commonLibs1"/>
    <fileset dir="${lib}">
        <include name="qux.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</union>

<war ...>
    <lib refid="serverLibs"/>
    ...
</war>

<manifestclasspath property="tmpClassPath" jarfile="./placeholdername.jar">
    <classpath>
        <resources refid="clientLibs"/>
    </classpath>
</classpath>

<jar ...>
    ...
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${tmpClasspath}"/>
    </manifest>
</jar>
```

But:

```
build.xml:1067: serverLibs doesn't denote a zipfileset or a fileset
```

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lib` nested element of `war` only accepts a `fileset` or a `zipfileset`. Other resource collections like `union` are not supported. You may have a few ways to convert it to a `fileset`. If the `union` needs to be kept to be used somewhere else, then you can create a `path` element from it and use the Ant-Contrib [`pathtofileset`](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/pathtofileset.html) task to convert it to a `fileset`:

```
<union id="serverLibs">
    <fileset refid="commonLibs1"/>
    <fileset dir="${lib}">
        <include name="qux.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</union>

<path id="serverLibsPath">
    <resources refid="serverLibs" />
</path>

<pathtofileset pathrefid="serverLibsPath" name="serverLibsFileset" dir="${lib}" />

<war ...>
   <lib refid="serverLibsFileset"/>
   ...
</war>
```

Or you can skip Ant-Contrib and use [`mappedresources`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#mappedresources) with the `path` created above (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039505/ant-script-prevent-duplication-of-jar-in-javac-classpath-war-lib) for an example).

A simpler way (if the `union` is only used by the `war` task) is to remove the union and just specify the combination of filesets in multiple `lib` elements:

```
<war ...>
   <lib refid="commonLibs1"/>
   <lib dir="${lib}">
       <include name="qux.jar"/>
   </lib>
   ...
</war>
```